# Lost when trying to get good time series prediction results (regression problem) even after trying many things

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, time-series, regression

I'm not able to get good results after a long time testing when using TensorFlow to predict time series data (regression problem). I don't know if the problem is with the data (little quantity and/or low quality) or with the model (or if there is a problem with both) (although I have tried several and tested various combinations of hyperparameters). I'm really tired and I don't know what else to do. What would you do if you were in my place? Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.